# Is Opc Server Available in Siemens Sinumerik Cnc?

Tags: opc, cnc, siemens, kepserverex

I have a research about connection between siemens sinumerik cnc and kepserverex.
Is opc server available 810 d and 840d sl x 127 ?

When looking at kepserver site , there is a [post](https://www.kepware.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/2008/can-kepserverex-communicate-to-a-siemens-sinumerik/) about it, how to connect sinumerik cnc with kepserverex. Regarding this post , there are 3 ways to do it. I have to figure out which way or ways must choose.

If opc server available, then which one is available opc da or opc ua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to this question. Depending on this  [post](https://www.inventcom.net/support/siemens/sinumerik-840d-828d-opc-ua-sw-45)
840d sl model has an opc ua server. But only for v4.5 software version and higher.

810d is an old product and it doesn't have an opc da or opc ua server.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Matrikon OPC or OSIsoft's one for the test purposes.